# Intent with custom action

Tags: android

Is there a way to construct an intent with custom action? I mean like `ACTION_CUSTOM`.

```
bundle_details.putString("query_details", searchIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
bundle_details.putString("type", SS);
listIntent.putExtras(bundle_details);
startActivity(listIntent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with:

```
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "ACTION_SEARCH_CUSTOM";

Intent listIntent = new Intent(TestDetails.this, SimpleSearch.class);
listIntent.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
```